# removing footer

Tags: magento

i tried to remove footer sitemap from customer account pages in magento . i changed local.xml file by adding code in sections

```
     <reference name="footer">
        <remove name="footer_sitemap" />
    </reference>
```

And I have strange problem. In my project i have 4 main categories (subshops). When i go to login from 2-nd and 3-rd category than footer disabled but when i go to login page from anothe categories  footer present.... maybe problem in URL? or cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ant I believe your problem will be because the footer is cached.

I had the same problem when I put a twitter feed in mine.

Try this - http://ken.edmonds-commerce.co.uk/magento/disable-footer-block-caching-in-magento/